# Use of queries in CSV files with user input

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, csv

I have the CSV file:

```
                                  Movie     Budget  Worldwide Gross  Year
0                                  2012  200000000        791217826  2009
1                               Aladdin  183000000       1050693953  2019
2                   Alice in Wonderland  200000000       1025468216  2010
3                               Aquaman  160000000       1148485886  2018
4                                Avatar  237000000       2847246203  2009
```

and I have the following code:

```
opcion = datos[datos["Year"] == 2019 ]
```

this helped me just show the data from that year...

but my problem is that the year (in this case 2019) needs to be provided by the user (or any other year that they would want to look for) and I dont know how to use int(input()) in order to do that.

thank you

Comment: `opcion = datos[datos["Year"] == int(input())]` or replace the number `2019` with a variable that you read using `int(input())` on a separate line.

Comment: thank you!      I get this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' i'll try the other way :)

Comment: The input still has to be a valid number.

Comment: It worked! I used usuario = int(input('cual es el a? '))
opcion = datos[datos["Year"] == usuario ]
opcion... Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A snippet of code to catch exception

```py
try:
    year = input("Enter a year: ")
    opcion = datos[datos["Year"] == int(year)]
    if opcion.empty:
        print(f"No result for year '{year}'")
except ValueError:
    print(f"'{year}' is not a valid date")
```